# How to get its own job-id from a running Dataproc job?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

Let's assume we instantiated a workflow-template that consists of only one job. Or even making it simpler, we submitted a single job

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark --cluster cluster-a ./some_job.py
```

As a result of submitting this command, a new job-id will be generated. Question: Is there any way to read this auto-generated job-id in `./some_job.py` script?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can run this python code from outside a dataproc cluster
2. Change region by the region where the cluster resides
3. If you need credentials you can pass it to the client

```
from google.cloud import dataproc_v1
from google.cloud.dataproc_v1 import *

project_id = "project-id"
region = "region_id"
# create a client for a specific region
client = dataproc_v1.JobControllerClient(client_options={
    'api_endpoint': 'region_id-dataproc.googleapis.com'
})
request = dataproc_v1.ListJobsRequest(project_id=project_id,region=region,)
page_result = client.list_jobs(request=request)

# List all jobs of the given type and retrieve their job IDs
job_ids = [job.reference.job_id for job in page_result.jobs]

# Print the job IDs to the console
print(job_ids)
```

[image]

Comment: wow, I hope this works. I am about to test it. I am not sure though why `/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/?recursive=true` didn't return the aforementioned `/instance/attributes/dataproc-job-id` resource for me... Because this is what I checked first. I will test and be back soon

Comment: @itlsNaz bummer, I got 404 `The requested URL <code>/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/dataproc-job-id</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.`.

Comment: The list of avaialble attributes:
`dataproc-agent-output-directory dataproc-bucket dataproc-cloud-logging-enabled dataproc-cluster-configuration-directory dataproc-cluster-name dataproc-cluster-properties dataproc-cluster-properties-file dataproc-cluster-uuid dataproc-datanode-enabled dataproc-initialization-script-count dataproc-master dataproc-master-additional dataproc-notebooks-url dataproc-option-run-init-actions-early dataproc-protocol-spec dataproc-region dataproc-role dataproc-temp-bucket dataproc-worker-count `

Comment: There is a cluster uuid, but nothing close to dataproc-job-id

Comment: the cluster uuID is Universally Unique Identifier  of the cluster , do you find the job if you do: ```gcloud dataproc jobs describe JOB_ID --region=REGION```

Comment: the point is that I don't know JOB_ID. Your code returns 404 because there is no resource called `/instance/attributes/dataproc-job-id`. I posted the full list of the available attributes and the `dataproc-job-id` is missing there. I hope I am clear now.

Comment: hmm I see , I will update my answer